# JPanel não aparece no JDialog

Tags: java, swing

Eu estou resolvendo uma atividade com o seguinte enunciado: Crie um aplicativo para exibir em uma janela JDialog oito componentes JPanel. Cada painel deve ser colorido com uma das oito cores da Tabela 1.

[image: Figura 1]

Em cada painel deve ser escrito a palavra que traduz o significado da cor. Usar fonte de tamanho 18.
Cada painel deve ser colorido usando uma cor da Tabela 1, especificando a quantidade de cada componente RGB (Red, Green, Blue) que corresponde ao significado da cor. Use a classe java.awt.Color.
Deve ser implementando apenas um único método paintComponent para pintar os 8 painéis e escrever o significado de cada cor.

**O problema é que o meu JPanel não aparece no JDialog.** E estou sem ideias de como fazer para ele aparecer.

Segue o codigo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SigCoresGUI extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Color[] cores = { new Color(255, 255, 255), new Color(249, 206, 137), new Color(255, 128, 0),
            new Color(255, 0, 0), new Color(244, 102, 174), new Color(5, 120, 203), new Color(116, 186, 160),
            new Color(0, 0, 0) };
    private String[] sig = { "Paz", "Energia", "Criatividade", "Paixão", "Ternura", "Tranquilidade", "Harmonia",
            "Elegância" };
    private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);

    public SigCoresGUI() {
        super();
        Desenha desenha = new Desenha();
        add(desenha);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Desenha extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(cores[i]);
                panel.setFont(font);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(sig[i]);
                label.setFont(font);
                if (i > 0)
                    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                panel.add(label);
                add(panel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class SigTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SigCoresGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos problemas é que você está tentando criar os paineis coloridos durante o processo de desenho do painel `Desenha`, por isso nada é exibido. O método `paintComponents` serve para desenhar aquele componente na sua tela, e para adicionar outros componentes a este, é preciso que o mais externo já esteja completamente desenhado. Pelo que entendi do problema, o uso de `paintComponents` é uma exigência, o que faz com que você tenha que adotar uma abordagem diferente desta que está usando.

Você consegue colorir um componente ainda em sua construção utilizando a própria classe `Graphics` recebida como parâmetro. `Graphics.setColor` define a cor a ser usada naquele contexto, combinada com o método `Graphics.fillRect` é possível forçar o preenchimento por completo do componente.

Também é possível desenhar strings neste método, definindo sua cor com o método já citado, definindo a fonte com o `Graphics2D.setFont`  e desenhando por si a string com `Graphics.drawString`. É necessário converter `Graphics` para `Graphics2D` pois o método responsável por pintar a string na tela se encontra nesta ultima classe, que é uma "versão melhorada" da primeira.

Dito isto, o código fica assim:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SigCoresGUI extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Color[] cores = { new Color(255, 255, 255), new Color(249, 206, 137), new Color(255, 128, 0),
            new Color(255, 0, 0), new Color(244, 102, 174), new Color(5, 120, 203), new Color(116, 186, 160),
            new Color(0, 0, 0) };
    private String[] sig = { "Paz", "Energia", "Criatividade", "Paixão", "Ternura", "Tranquilidade", "Harmonia",
            "Elegância" };
    private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);

    public SigCoresGUI() {
        super();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            add(desenhaPainel(cores[i], sig[i]));
        }

        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel desenhaPainel(Color cor, String significado) {
        return new JPanel() {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setColor(cor);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2.setColor(cor.getRGB() == Color.black.getRGB() ? Color.white : Color.black);
                g2.setFont(font);
                g2.drawString(significado, 5, 15);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new SigCoresGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

o resultado:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Repare que configurei a cor 2 vezes, na primeira pra preencher o componente, e na segunda pra desenhar a string. Fiz um pequeno *workaround* pra poder inverter a cor da fonte no ultimo quadrado, pois sendo o fundo preto e a fonte preta, ela obviamente some.

Comment: Obrigado, graças a sua resposta consegui arrumar aqui.